# Python mock variable in __init__ method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest-mock

I'm trying to mock a variable in the `__init__()` method. My code looks like that:

```py
import gitlab
from loguru import logger


class GetMRsInfo:
    def __init__(self, gitlab_endpoint: str, private_token: str, project_name_with_namespace: str):
        kernel_git = gitlab.Gitlab(gitlab_endpoint, private_token=private_token)
        kernel_git.auth()
        self.project = kernel_git.projects.get(project_name_with_namespace)

    def get_merge_request_state(self, mr_id: int) -> str:
        try:
            merge_request = self.project.mergerequests.get(mr_id)
            return merge_request.state
        except gitlab.exceptions.GitlabGetError:
            logger.warning(f"Couldn't get an MR state. MR ID: {mr_id}")
            return ""
```

The idea is to mock `self.project` it so I could use it in tests later.

I've tried to do it in the way but it doesn't work:

```py
@patch('src.get_merge_request_info.GetMRsInfo.project')
def test_python_is(get_mr_project):
    get_mr_project.return_value = MagicMock()
    git = GetMRsInfo(gitlab_endpoint="https://example.gitlab.com", private_token="ASD123", project_name_with_namespace="test/example/com")
    merge_request_state = git.get_merge_request_state(123)
    assert merge_request_state, 'opened'
```

It would be great if you suggest a solution. Thanks.

Comment: I would heavily refactor this. `GetMRsInfo.__init__` should take a `Gitlab` instance (or at least a `Gitlab`-like instance) as an argument. Then you can simply pass whatever stub or mock you like when instantiating it, rather than having to patch function-internal objects.

Comment: You can define an additional *class* method that takes an endpoint, token, and project name, which will use that information to create the `Gitlab` instance to pass to `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

You are patching the wrong thing. *Instances* of `GetMRsInfo` have a `project` attribute, not the class `GetMRsInfo` itself. What you want to patch is `Gitlab` itself.

```
@patch('src.get_merge_request_info.gitlab.Gitlab')
def test_python_is(mock_gitlab):
    mock_gitlab.return_value.projects.get.return_value.merge_requests.get.return_value = "opened"
    git = GetMRsInfo(gitlab_endpoint="https://example.gitlab.com", private_token="ASD123", project_name_with_namespace="test/example/com")
    merge_request_state = git.get_merge_request_state(123)
    assert merge_request_state, 'opened'
```

The first assignment is a bit complicated. But remember:

- Any mock can be called, with the return value specified by configuring the `Mock`'s `return_value` attribute.
- Accessing any attribute of a `Mock` produces another `Mock`.

So

1. `mock_gitlab.return_value` is the `Mock` assigned to `kernel_git`
2. That `Mock`'s `projects` attribute is a `Mock`, and so is *that* `Mock`'s `get` attribute.
3. Calling the previous `mock` will yield a `Mock` whose `merge_requests` attribute will be a `Mock` with a `get` attribute that is a `Mock` which you want to return `'opened'` when it is called.

---

A better idea, though, is to avoid hard-coding the things you'll want to patch during testing. Start by dumbing down `__init__` so that it *receives* a project, rather than having to interface with Gitlab in the first place.

```
class GetMRsInfo:
    def __init__(self, project):
        self.project = project

    @classmethod
    def from_gitlab(cls, gitlab_endpoint: str, private_token: str, project_name_with_namespace: str):
        kernel_git = gitlab.Gitlab(gitlab_endpoint, private_token=private_token)
        kernel_git.auth()
        project = kernel_git.projects.get(project_name_with_namespace)
        return cls(project)

    def get_merge_request_state(self, mr_id: int) -> str:
        try:
            merge_request = self.project.mergerequests.get(mr_id)
            return merge_request.state
        except gitlab.exceptions.GitlabGetError:
            logger.warning(f"Couldn't get an MR state. MR ID: {mr_id}")
            return ""
```

This simple change means that:

1. In your projection code, you'll use `mrinfo = GetMRsInfo.from_gitlab(...)` instead of `mrinfo = GetMRsInfo(...)`
2. In your test, you'll create a simple mock project without having to go through `Gitlab` at all, which simplifies defining the `Mock`. Note you won't have to specify a bunch of dummy Gitlab details that aren't used anyway.

```
def test_python_is(mock_gitlab):
    project = Mock()
    project.merge_requests.get.return_value = "opened"
    git = GetMRsInfo(project)
    merge_request_state = git.get_merge_request_state(123)
    assert merge_request_state, 'opened'
```

3. If you want to write a test for the class method, that's simpler, too. For example,

   def test_classmethod():
   mock_gitlab = Mock()
   obj = GetMRsInfo.from_gitlab("endpoint", "token", "name")
   assert mock_gitlab.auth.called
   ...

You can configure `mock_gitlab` as before to ensure, for example, that `obj` comes from a method call to some Gitlab instance's `projects` attribute.